# Does protobuf-net support System.Collections.Queue?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I run my client/server application with protobuf-net instead of binaryformatter and i get next exception: **"No serializer defined for type: System.Collections.Queue"**. 
I am not sure completely and may be the reason is i did something wrong...
because i have already asked about Dictionary/List and these types are supported ( [Can I serialize an object (containing members: Dictionary, List... etc) in Mono and deserialize it in MS.NET or vice versa by using protobuf-net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504275/can-i-serialize-an-object-containing-members-dictionary-list-etc-in-mono) ).

I just read from: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted
*"supported: 
**any type which implements IEnumerable and has an Add(T) method** "*
and Queue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx does not have Add(T)...

**Question:**
But i want to be sure completely. Does protobuf-net support **System.Collections.Queue** or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current time, no: it does not. I would suggest treating the data as a list for the purposes of serialization. For reference, `XmlSerializer` hates it too - here's the `XmlSerializer` output for `Queue<string>`:

> "You must implement a default accessor on System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] because it inherits from ICollection."

Comment: The question seems to be about the non-generic `Queue`, not the generic `Queue<T>`.

Comment: @svick the same applies, though; with the added complication that *additionally* with a non-generic type we'd also need to tell it what item-type we should expect